# Parse error on input 'Show'

Tags: haskell

i have written the follwing code:

```
data Genre = Nonfiction | Novel | Biography deriving (Eq, Show)

type Name = (String, String)
type Date = (Int, Int, Int)
type Book = ABook Genre
        Name 
        String
        Date 
        Int
deriving Show

genre :: Book -> Genre 
genre (ABook g _ _ _ _) = g

author :: Book -> Name 
author (ABook _ a _ _ _) = a

title :: Book -> String 
title (ABook _ _ t _ _) = t

date :: Book -> Date
date (ABook _ _ _ d _) = d

pages :: Book -> Int
pages (ABook _ _ _ _ p) = p

year :: Book -> Int 
year b = let (_ , _ , b) = date b in y


publishedIn :: Int -> [Book] -> [Book]
publishedIn x xs = filter findYear xs 

findYear:: Book -> Bool
findYear x | year x == 2014 = True
           | otherwise      = False
```

The functions from genre until year are helpfunctions which I try to include in the higher order functions like filter etc.
But the compiler shows me the following error message:

```
Parse error on input 'Show'
```

What can I do against that ?

Comment: Indent the `deriving` clause and change it from `type Book` to `data Book`.  @Sibi has pointed out a couple other problems, but the reason it isn't compiling right now is because you have `deriving` at the top level applied to a type alias, not a data type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are number of issues with your code:

1)  `type` is used for creating new name for an existing type. But in your case, this will result in compilation error because you are trying to define new data constructor here:

```
type Book = ABook Genre Name String Date Int deriving (Show)
```

So, use the `data` keyword to create proper type and data constructor. i.e:

```
data Book = ABook Genre Name String Date Int deriving Show
```

2) There is a problem with your function `year` :

```
year :: Book -> Int     
year b = let (_ , _ , b) = date b in y
```

As you see, there is no `y` there. Probably you meant something like this:

```
year b = let (_ , _ , y) = date b in y
```

---

With that being said, you should use the record syntax instead of manually creating helper function.

```
data Book = ABook {
  genre :: Genre,
  author :: Name,
  title :: String,
  date :: Date
}
```

Here, you get free accessor functions named `genre` , `author`, etc without writing them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`type` defines a type synonym and what you want is a new data type. You can do this by replacing `type Book = ...` with `data Book = ...`. Also, there needs to be at least one space before `deriving` since it is part of the data type definition.